# Can't get an Angular App to work inside a MVC view from layout

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project that uses ASP.NET MVC, AngularJS I am calling a mvc controller from AngularJS. I am getting an jsonresult as in the call to a MVC controller from AngularJS .

**branches controller**

```
public class BranchesController : Controller
{

private IRepositoryBase<Branches> BrancheRepository;

 public BranchesController(IRepositoryBase<Branches> brancheRepository)
 {
    this.BrancheRepository = brancheRepository;
 }
// GET: Branches
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var branches = BrancheRepository.GetAll();




        //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        //{
        //    branches = branches.Where(s => s.Branch_Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        //}

         return View(branches);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetAllBranches()
    {

        var branches = BrancheRepository.GetAll();






        return Json(branches, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="branch-controller">
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Branch Details - Grid CRUD operations
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead style="background-color:lightblue;">
            <tr>
                <th> Branch Address</th>
                <th> Branch Email</th>
                <th>Branch Name</th>
                <th>Branch Notes</th>
                <th> Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="branche in Branches">
                  <td>{{branche.Branch_ID}}</td>
                <td>{{branche.Branch_Address}}</td>
                <td>{{branche.Branch_email}}</td>
                <td>{{branche.Branch_Name}}</td>
                <td>{{branche.Branch_Notes}}</td>

                <td style="width:200px;">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Update</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**FetchData.js**

```
   var MyApp = angular.module('mybranches', []);

  MyApp.controller('branchcontroller', function ($scope, RecordService) { //inject $scope and    RecordServce.
   $scope.Branches = null;
   RecordService.GetAllBranches().then(function (d) {
    $scope.Branches = d.data; // Success
}, function () {
    alert('Failed'); // Failed
  });
});

   //The concept of the factory service is same as service layer in ASP.NET MVC Application.
   MyApp.factory('RecordService', function ($http) {
   var fac = {};
   //GetRecord function will call the GetStudentRecord action method.
    fac.GetAllBranches = function () {
    return $http.get('Branches/GetAllBranches');
    };
    return fac;
    });
```

**Layout.cshtml**

```
<body class="rtls" ng-app="mybranches">

<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    @Html.Partial("_Navigation")

    <!-- Page wraper -->
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

        <!-- Top Navbar -->
        @Html.Partial("_TopNavbar")

        <!-- Main view  -->
        @RenderBody()

        <!-- Footer -->
        @Html.Partial("_Footer")

    </div>
    <!-- End page wrapper-->

</div>
<!-- End wrapper-->

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
<script src="~/Scripts/AngularJSApp/Branches/FetchData.js"></script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/plugins/metsiMenu")
@Scripts.Render("~/plugins/pace")
@Scripts.Render("~/plugins/slimScroll")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/inspinia")

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

> When i hit Branches Index action result controller from angular it gives me this json result instead of display the list of branches view i don't know the reason of that i think that angullar not working in index.cshtml view i don't know why because when i replaced the html code from index.cshtml to layout.cshtml it works fine

**this is the result when i hit the index action result in branches controller **

```html
[
 {
"Branch_ID": 1,
"Branch_Name": "sdsds",
"Branch_Address": "sfsdfsdf",
"Branch_email": "sdfsdfsdf",
"Branch_Notes": "sfsffsfd",
"Branch_Manager": null,
"Branch_Phone": null,
"Branch_TimeFrom": "/Date(-2208996000000)/",
"Branch_TimeTo": "/Date(-2208996000000)/",
"saturday": false,
"sunday": false,
"monday": false,
"tuesday": false,
"wednesday": false,
"thursday": false,
"friday": false,
"Departments": null
 }
]
```

Comment: `Index()` returns a Json result, that's why you see that output

Comment: @BillP how can i fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index method should return the View not the Json:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

This will render the `Index.cshtml`. In Index.cshtml you need to add Layout reference:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Also, remove the dublicate code from layout html file

Comment: After i changes the code to this code  gives me an `alert('Failed');` from FetchData.js

Comment: This has to do with the http get request that fails,we don't have enough information for that . Did index html showed up with the changes?

Comment: yes index.cshtml showed but with no data because  http get request fails

Comment: This is a completely different problem. As html view problem resolved, create a new question and focus to the $http error, providing only the associated code samples.

Comment: can you come into teamviewer to see the issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205144/discussion-between-bill-p-and-hashim).